# docker-compose for LN works fine with regtest but error with testnet

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network

I'm using this docker-compose file: https://github.com/zeltsi/lnsim

It works fine with regest (without modification)

Then I changed regtest for testnet (all 4 occurences)

Now I have this error:

> lightning-cli: Connecting to 'lightning-rpc': Connection refused

I have

```
> lightning-cli --version
v0.12.1
```

Both bitcoin nodes are synced.

So what is the difference between regtest and testnet ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this. Runs fine when just replacing all 4 "regtest" with "testnet". Do you mind sharing your modified full docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I used the docker-compose file in the link I've posted

Comment: https://github.com/zeltsi/lnsim/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: That's the original docker compose file. I'm looking for your modified version, since I can't reproduce the issue by following your steps.